# Filter array of objects based on criteria in another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filtering, javascript-objects

I want to filter items from the `categories` array based on the criteria in the `otherCategories` array.

If `otherCategories` contains an object where `title` matches one title from `categories.subCategory[i].title` and `name` matches `categories.subCategory[i].details.name`, then filter only that object e.g "item1" from `categories`.

```
var categories = [
{
    title:"item1",
    subCategory:[
        {
            title:"subCat1",
            details:{
                name:"detail1",
                email:"test@test.com"
            }
        },
        {
            title:"subCat2",
            details:{
                name:"detail2",
                email:"test@test.com"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    title:"item2",
    subCategory:[
        {
            title:"subCat1",
            details:{
                name:"detail3",
                email:"test@test.com"
            }
        },
        {
            title:"subCat2",
            details:{
                name:"detail2",
                email:"test@test.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
]

var otherCategories = [
{
    title:"subCat1",
    name:"detail1"        
}
]
```

Expected result

```
categories = [
{
    title:"item1",
    subCategory:[
        {
            title:"subCat1",
            details:{
                name:"detail1",
                email:"test@test.com"
            }
        },
        {
            title:"subCat2",
            details:{
                name:"detail2",
                email:"test@test.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: please show expected result

Comment: for( var i in categories) { if( categories[i].title == "item1") console.log(categories[i]) }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) & [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

- Convert the `otherCategories` array to an object with title as key and name as value
- Filter `categories` array where some `subCategory` exists with matching values

```js
var categories = [{title:"item1",subCategory:[{title:"subCat1",details:{name:"detail1",email:"test@test.com"}},{title:"subCat2",details:{name:"detail2",email:"test@test.com"}}]},{title:"item2",subCategory:[{title:"subCat1",details:{name:"detail3",email:"test@test.com"}},{title:"subCat2",details:{name:"detail2",email:"test@test.com"}}]}];
var otherCategories = [{title:"subCat1",name:"detail1"}];
var obj = otherCategories.reduce((a,c) => Object.assign(a,{[c.title]:c.name}), {});

categories = categories.filter(v => v.subCategory.some(o => obj[o.title] === o.details.name));
console.log(categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that will usually work for simple objects like the ones in your example, is to convert your `otherCategories` array to an array of "stringified" objects, and then filter `categories` by comparing "stringified" versions of the desired `subCategory` key value pairs to the converted `otherCategories` array.

Important to note, however, that object property order is not guaranteed in JavaScript (although many browsers will preserve property order). That means that this approach may not work in some situations and an approach like the one suggested by [@NikhilAggarwal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1132354/nikhil-aggarwal) is more stable.

For example:

```js
const categories = [{title: "item1", subCategory: [{title: "subCat1", details: {name: "detail1", email: "test@test.com"}},{title: "subCat2", details: {name: "detail2", email: "test@test.com"}}]}, {title: "item2", subCategory: [{title: "subCat1", details: {name: "detail3", email: "test@test.com"}},{title: "subCat2", details: {name: "detail2", email: "test@test.com"}}]}];
const otherCategories = [{title: "subCat1", name: "detail1"}];
const matches = otherCategories.map((item) => JSON.stringify(item));
const results = categories.filter((item) => {
  for (const sub of item.subCategory) {
    const match = JSON.stringify({title: sub.title, name: sub.details.name});
    if (matches.includes(match)) {
      return true;
    }
    
    return false;
  }
});

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `map` the categories to the results by `filtering` the subCategories:

```
  function matches(sub, filters) {
    return filters.some(filter => filter.title === sub.title && filter.name === sub.name);
 }

 const result = categories.map(({ title, subCategories }) => ({ title, subCategories: subCategories.filter(sub => matches(sub, otherCategories)) }));
```